# Binding in ListView in XAML Xamarin

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, android-listview

Could someone answer me the question about listview?
I have variable MyDatas which is collection of listview (and it works):

```
<ListView 
            x:Name="lstView"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyDatas}"> ...
```

Next I have (part of my code but is enough for explaining the problem):

```
<Label Grid.Row="0"
       Grid.Column="1" 
       Text="{Binding E1}" 
       FontSize="{Binding FProp.Size1}" 
       FontAttributes="{Binding FProp.Atrib1}"/>
```

E1 is a field of MyDatas and this binding works correct. I have property of fonts in another variable FProp (FProp.Size1 and FProp.Atrib1) and this is problem! How can I use this another variable in this listview?
If FProp is used outside of listview all is ok, if I use it in listview it does not work.

Thank you for help

Comment: according to the API docs, FontSize is not a bindable property

Comment: isn't it? There's a bindable property marked as backing store property for fontsize https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.label.fontsizeproperty?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: the docs may be wrong.  Generally the ones that are bindable say "this is a bindable property" in the property list

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will try it for example in label outside listview.

Comment: I checked in in my aplication. It's true that we can't bind the property FontSize and FontAttributes. There are not bindaable properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are not binding correctly the font size.
You are referencing a property named `Size1` inside the object `FProp` which is not in your current binding context. The main problem is that you can only have one binding context per object. So, you should include the `Size1` and `Atrib1`in your `MyDatas` object in order to make it available for the label. Another option is to change the binding context of the listview to point to `FProp` then you could access the values on the labels, but you will lose access to the `E1` value. So you will need to choose how to fix this problem depending on the options provided.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I was afraid of that :-( I thought that I can't use together two different variables in one listview. Therefore I asked about this. Are you sure it is? If yes I have to find another way to resolve this problem. I will include then the property Size1 of FProp to my variable MyDatas which is obesrved in listview.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an x:Name to your ListView, let's say `listView1` and use something like this

```
{Binding Path=BindingContext.FProp.Size1, Source={x:Reference listView1}}
```

Comment: Thank you :-) I will try immediately.

Comment: But it will be work if FontSize and FontAttributes are not a bindeable properties?

Comment: I checked. Your idea is very good for using property of another variable in our listview. Really it's FProp.Size1 is visible in listview. But it's not a bindeable property and it doesn't set FontSize. FontSize is set to default value.

Comment: Uhm source code seems to show label as bindable https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Label.cs (I will test when I'm back at my desk)... in any case you can use a behaviour attached property to make your own bindable property

Comment: :-) I will check it... Thank you. Tell me what was result of your test, please

Comment: Hey I did test FontSize and it is a bindable property! I did a button that increases fontsize on the ViewModel and works like a charm so confirmed that it is bindable. If you share more of your code, I might be able to help.